# Can a single cite within a citation reference more than one url/accessed date pairs?

Tags: csl, citeproc-js

Let's say that I have a reference such as:

```
title "Hello World"
urls
 - http://example.com/foo (accessed 20/03/2018)
 - http://example.com/bar (accessed 10/05/2015)
```

*(And let's say that the above reference is processed into a form that a CSL processor can understand; citeproc-js in this case)*

Does the CSL specification allow to produce a citation (from this only reference) that looks like this?

> Hello World! http://example.com/foo (accessed 20/03/2018); http://example.com/bar (accessed 10/05/2015)

I know I could support one pair with this: (simplified style for the example)

```xml
<citation>
  <layout>
    <text variable="title" suffix=" "/>
    <group>
      <text variable="URL" suffix=" "/>
      <date variable="accessed" prefix="(" suffix=")">
        <date-part name="day" suffix="/"/>
        <date-part name="month" suffix="/"/>
        <date-part name="year"/>
      </date>
    </group>
  </layout>
</citation>
```

**But how do I "iterate" over multiple pairs?**

It doesn't seem that the [CSL specification](https://docs.citationstyles.org/en/master/specification.html) nor the [schema for CSL data](https://github.com/citation-style-language/schema/blob/master/csl-data.json) support this. Am I wrong?

Comment: Correct, CSL doesn't support multiple values for standard variables (only for names) - they take a single string, so the data you have in your YAML is invalid for CSL purposes.

FWIW, this has never come up as a request in the history of CSL. From a citation perspective, these should just be two separate citations.

Comment: @adam.smith Could it also be two cites (i.e. from two separate references) in one citation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with two citations, e.g.:

```
- type: webpage
  URL:  http://example.com/foo (accessed 20/03/2018)
- type: webpage
  URL:  http://example.com/bar (accessed 10/05/2015)
```

Style snippet

```xml
<citation>
  <layout delimiter="; ">
    <group>
      <text variable="URL" suffix=" "/>
      <date variable="accessed" prefix="(" suffix=")">
        <date-part name="day" suffix="/"/>
        <date-part name="month" suffix="/"/>
        <date-part name="year"/>
      </date>
    </group>
  </layout>
</citation>
```

And then simply include "Hello World!" in the text. Note the delimiter in layout that determines how the two elements are separated.

Comment: Just want to make sure I understand the spec semantics: Given two references, this would produce one citation made of two cites (each cite refers to one reference only), right?

Comment: That's exactly right, yes:
"The cs:citation element describes the formatting of citations, which consist of one or more references (“cites”) to bibliographic sources."