# Permalink URLs in CSL Bibliography

Tags: permalinks, bibliography, csl

I'm writing a research paper in deep learning, so some of my citations are inevitably to things like Medium posts. To avoid link rot, I created perma.cc links to these posts; using my reference manager (Mendeley), I added both the original URL and the permalink URL.

In the exported BibTeX file, I see that both URLs are included in one URL field, separated by a space. However, the CSL processor I'm using only includes the first URL in the bibliography.

[A previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60526355/can-a-single-cite-within-a-citation-reference-more-than-one-url-accessed-date-pa) asked how to change a CSL style to include two URL fields, and the answer was "CSL can't do that", but there wasn't any discussion of what a use case would be for that. So, if I can't do that with CSL, what SHOULD I do? Is it okay (academically) to cite a perma.cc link but not the original URL? Is there another field I can abuse to store a permalink?

I don't want this citation to depend on Medium staying in service indefinitely. Especially since the page doesn't load on the Wayback machine (which apparently gets caught in reload loops with Medium articles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the CSL end, you can basically use any variable you want for an archived link -- most logically I'd suggest `archive`. You might have to adjust the citation style to print that -- that'd depend on the style.

Unfortunately, Mendeley doesn't have a field for archive, so you'd either have to use something less suitable (maybe `Series` mapping to CSL `collection`? -- no really good options I'm seeing) or, if using the Desktop version of Mendeley, add archive to the Notes in the form:
`archive: perma.cc/9265-T4NB`. That gets picked up by citation styles.